# Twitter message posting issue ( Request failed with error: Error Domain=HTTP Code=410 "The operation couldn’t be completed. in ios app

Tags: ios, twitter

One year back I have done one ios app and integrated the twitter+OAuth in the app . When I was releasing my app it is working fine . But now it is giving the error **Request E51F2651-7D60-4670-9513-2D6494661959 failed with error: Error Domain=HTTP Code=410 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 410.)"** . Can anyone please tell me how to solve this issue .

My app permissions in Twitter is  **Read, write, and direct messages** and Request URI is **api.twitter.com/1** . I have searched a lot about this issue . Most of the people are saying that we have to choose the application type to Client only but I didn't find this option in my twitter account . Please give me some guidelines .

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you are using the iOS Twitter functionality, or another framework (but the oAuth makes me think it's another framework). The Twitter V1 API has been deprecated and retired. You should now use the 1.1 version:

https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired

This means the URI should have 1.1 in it, as opposed to just "1".

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

I would try updating the framework you are using, or perhaps switching to the built in Twitter functionality, which streamlines the authentication process if the user has a Twitter account on their phone.

Comment: If this has fixed your issue, please go ahead and accept the answer as correct, thanks!

Comment: No Wayfarer I dont know how to integrate the v1.1 could you help me?